# Align DIVs in a row Bootstrap - w/ text centered on image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

(bootstrap 3 and Laravel 5.1 framework)

I have 3 divs in a Boostrap row.  Each div has an image and some text that is centered on that image.  I would like all three DIVs to be side by side (vertically centered in the row) but I can't seem to achieve it.  I have searched through a number of posts but mostly they are simple solutions and aren't working for the complexity I have with mine.

### HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row"> <!--Timer and scoring of match -->
  <div class="wrapcontrols" style="float: left">
    <img src="/img/leftminus.png">
    <img src="/img/blackscore.png">
    <img src="/img/rightplus.png">
    <h2 class="clocktime">5</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <img src="/img/clockbackground.png">
    <h2 class="clocktime">03:00</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="wrapcontrols" style="float: right">
    <img src="/img/leftminus.png">
    <img src="/img/yellowscore.png">
    <img src="/img/rightplus.png">
    <h2 class="clocktime">5</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.wrap {
width: 152px;
height:auto;
vertical-align:middle;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative; }

.clocktime {
position: absolute;
font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
font-weight: 400;
margin: auto;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
color:#fff;
height:36px;  }

.wrapcontrols {
width: 375px;
vertical-align:middle;
height: auto;
margin: auto;
text-align:center;
position:relative;  }
```

[Here is what it looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra4cW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, I added appropriate classes that are required for the Bootstrap.I also removed your inline CSS. I would also remove some CSS styles for wrapcontrols and wrap divs.

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row"> <!--Timer and scoring of match -->

      <div class="wrapcontrols col-sm-4">
        <img src="/img/leftminus.png">
        <img src="/img/blackscore.png">
        <img src="/img/rightplus.png">
        <h2 class="clocktime">5</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="wrap col-sm-4">
        <img src="/img/clockbackground.png">
        <h2 class="clocktime">03:00</h2>
      </div>

      <div class="wrapcontrols col-sm-4">
        <img src="/img/leftminus.png">
        <img src="/img/yellowscore.png">
        <img src="/img/rightplus.png">
        <h2 class="clocktime">5</h2>
      </div>

</div>
```

THis is the correct Bootstrap Structure:

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
    <div class="col-sm-4"></div>

</div><!--end row-->
```

Comment: Interesting... I didn't realize that by not including the column class that it could cause the vertical spacing to go crazy.  I added the column structure and I was able to then format based off of the columns and get the results I was looking for.  Thank you!